# Form fields updating values from mysql on selecting a value in drop down

Tags: javascript, php

I am developing a page in PHP. It has a `select drop down(user names)` and a form below containing user details. On selecting a particular user from drop down, details of selected user should be populated in form below. 
Am beginner to PHP. 
How to do this? Any simple solution

Comment: on change send a ajax request(or reload the page) and fetch the details and display ..a rough idea

Comment: This might help : http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/5/24/Example-of-jQuery-loading-form-fields

Answer (score 0):

You need to put dropdown in a form.
On change event of dropdown just post form on same URL with get method.
Check the paramenter in url and fetch data and display.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#userid').change(function(){
                $('#getUserData').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name='getUserData' id='getUserData' action='#' method='GET'>
        Select User : <select id='userid' name='userid'>
            <option value='1'>Lokendra</option>
            <option value='2'>Amit</option>
            <option value='3'>Nitin</option>
            <option value='4'>Rishabh</option>
        </select>

    </form>
    <?php
        $userArray=array(
                    1   =>  'Lokendra',
                    2   =>  'Amit',
                    3   =>  'Nitin',
                    4   =>  'Rishabh',
                );
        $postedData=$_REQUEST;
        // Fire your select query here and diplay data 

        if(isset($postedData['userid'])){
            echo "Selected User name =>".$userArray[$postedData['userid']];
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Dont forget to accept this answer if helps :)

Comment: I am unable to get this way. Can u please provide me a link or complete example to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it an AJAX request.
Follow the steps
Lets assume you make your post requests to user.php

```
<form id='getDetails' type='post' action='user.php'>
     <select id='users'>
        <option>AMAN</option>
        <option>ABHAY</option>
     </select>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('users').on('change', function(){
      var userVal = $('users option:selected').text();
      $.post('user.php',{user:userVal},function(data){
          console.log(data);
          //Populate the form by using data variable 
          //which contains the data you need
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

Make sure to include jQuery

Comment: I included jquery, even am unable to get data from url. Can u please provide me a link or complete example to do this